# HTTP POST using httr in R

Tags: r, curl, post, web-scraping, httr

I am trying to adapt my `curl` request from running it in `Terminal` to `R`. For this I am using the `httr` package. My request is as follows and works from `Terminal`

```
curl -u user@email.com:password -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST "https://catalogue.onda-dias.eu/dias-catalogue/Products(48809a01-71bc-4669-8639-f0528abcdafe)/Ens.Order"
```

My attempt to use `httr` `POST` function is as follows:

```
pars <- list(username='user@email.com', password='password')

res<-POST("https://catalogue.onda-dias.eu/dias-catalogue/Products(48809a01-71bc-4669-8639-f0528abcdafe)/Ens.Order", body = pars, add_headers('Content-Type'='application/json'))
```

I am getting a 401 error code. Do you know how should I properly convert my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using httr:authenticate

```
require(httr)

headers = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json')

r <- httr::POST(  url = 'https://catalogue.onda-dias.eu/dias-catalogue/Products(48809a01-71bc-4669-8639-f0528abcdafe)/Ens.Order'
                  , httr::add_headers(.headers=headers)
                  , httr::authenticate('user@email.com', 'password'))
```

Comment: I changed the name of the variable `headers` as it is causing confusion on the `POST` function. It seems to be a pck function. Doing that, I avoid the error and the script works fine. Thanks